# Is there a keyboard shortcut (hotkey) to open Terminal in macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

One of my primary tools used for programming is my Terminal. It makes my programming process more efficient when I'm able to quickly open a Terminal window.

In Ubuntu, I was using (<kbd>window</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to open Terminal. But now I use a Macbook at my programming job.

Sometimes I use Spotlight to search "Terminal", and press Enter.

I'd like to know if I can assign a keyboard hotkey to do it.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this question because it falls under the "tools used primarily for programming".  Programmers use the terminal primarily for running programming-related tasks.

Comment: @JonKiparsky The question is about having the Terminal open somewhere and opening a new window when another app has the focus.

Comment: Just because I think it's ridiculous... I'm reiterating what @GregKopff stated... "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming"... Gopal Prasad, the OP, clearly says "One of my primary tools used for programming is my Terminal." Like come on.. a solution to this is highly valuable.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question! There may be many people coming from Linux 
 (using desktops such as Unity, XFCE, Cinnamon, MATE, etc.) looking for functionality like this. The upvotes prove the interest.

Comment: [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/). I'm not trying to be facetious, seriously, just use iTerm2.

Comment: @Socrates I agree, but probably _AskDifferent_ is the more ideal location for this question, and _SO_ gets polluted/overused an awful lot. So I have some sympathy with why it was flagged.

Comment: @BenjaminR True, AskDifferent might be suitable for this. And then again, for many people the boundaries of what can be asked here in SO and what not are not fully clear.

Answer (score 164):

I tested the following procedure under macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G3020).

Launch Automator. Create a document of type “Quick Action”:

[image: quick action template]

(In older versions of macOS, use the “Service” template.)

In the new Automator document, add a “Run AppleScript” action. (You can type “run applescript” into the search field at the top of the action list to find it.) Here's the AppleScript to paste into the action:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        if it is running then
            do script ""
        end if
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

Set the “Workflow receives” popup to “no input”. It should look like this overall:

[image: workflow with applescript]

Save the document with the name “New Terminal”. Then go to the Automator menu (or the app menu in any running application) and open the Services submenu. You should now see the “New Terminal” quick action:

[image: New Terminal service menu item]

If you click the “New Terminal” menu item, you'll get a dialog box:

[image: permission dialog]

Click OK to allow the action to run. You'll see this dialog once in each application that's frontmost when you use the action. In other words, the first time you use the action while Finder is frontmost, you'll see the dialog. And the first time you use the action while Safari is frontmost, you'll see the dialog. And so on.

After you click OK in the dialog, Terminal should open a new window.

**To assign a keyboard shortcut to the quick action**, choose the “Services Preferences…” item from the Services menu. (Or launch System Preferences, choose the Keyboard pane, then choose the Shortcuts tab, then choose Services from the left-hand list.) Scroll to the bottom of the right-hand list and find the New Terminal service. Click it and you should see an “Add Shortcut” button:

[image: add shortcut button]

Click the button and press your preferred keyboard shortcut. Then, scratch your head, because (when I tried it) the Add Shortcut button reappears. But click the button again and you should see your shortcut:

[image: keyboard shortcut set]

Now you should be able to press your keyboard shortcut in most circumstances to get a new terminal window.

Comment: This works great for me except for when the Terminal app is not yet started. In such a case, then I get *two* new Terminal windows. I fixed this by changing the AppleScript to the following: on run {input, parameters}
 
 tell application "Terminal"
  if it is running then
   do script ""
  end if
  activate
 end tell
 return input
 
end run

Comment: @robmayoff I'm having some trouble implementing your script. It works just fine when I click the play button in Automator, however when I click the task under Services, an error pops up saying `The action "Run AppleScript" encountered an error`. Any ideas? I'm on OSX 10.12.1 if that matters.

Comment: I was having an issue where it would open a window if Terminal had no windows, but if there was one already open, it would just select that window. All I had to do was remove the word "shell" from the script.

Comment: @HoldenLewis Good call. `do script` is a Terminal command. `do shell script` is an AppleScript command that is similar but not the same.

Comment: @robmayoff The picture and the script you posted are slightly different. Can you confirm which one is correct?

Comment: Use the text script. The script in the screen shot opens two windows if Terminal wasn't already running. See @chrisdembia's comment.

Comment: I've got windows duplication problem ever with the latest update of this answer. I've fixed it with the following script `on run {input, parameters}
 tell application "Terminal"
  if not (exists window 1) then reopen
  activate
 end tell
end run`

Comment: @Axim the shortcut is only working when the "Keyboard" window of system preferences is open. When the "Keyboard" window is closed, it doesn't works.

Comment: @Axim, Even i was getting the same error "The action "Run AppleScript" encountered an error " , got fixed after adding  "return" . My final code is :
` on run {input, parameters}
 
 tell application "Terminal"
  if it is running then
   do script ""
  end if
  activate
 end tell
 
 return input
end run   `

Comment: @bazinga is right. And even with the keyboard preferences open, not all key combinations are valid.

Comment: but it still hardly ever works. usually hitting your shortcut will be ignored.

Comment: only doesn't work if you use a common shortcut. I use "ctrl + shift + F12"  that way the shortcut will not be over-ridden

Comment: for iTerm users, change `Terminal` to `iTerm` and change `do script ""` to `create window with default profile`

Comment: It works for me if automator is in focus but it doesn't seem to trap global keyboard input. Is there some step that needs to happen for automator to get access when other windows have focus?

Comment: to avoid duplication of windows, I just did ...tell application "Terminal" activate end tell...

Comment: Running the service directly from Automator always works, but trying to tie it to a keyboard shortcut never works. I even used the super-obscure ctrl-alt-shift-super-T, and still no luck. What's going on here?

Comment: I changed the script slightly to make it work correctly when Terminal app is closed:
 `tell application "Terminal"
  if it is running then
   do script ""
  else
   reopen
  end if
  activate
 end tell`

Answer (score 21):

As programmers we want the quickest, most fool-proof way to get our tools in order so we can start hacking. Here are how I got it to work in macOS 10.13.1 (High Sierra):

- Option 1: Go to `System Preferences | Keyboard | Shortcut | Services`.
  Under `Files and Folders` section, enable `New Terminal at Folder`
  and/or `New Terminal Tab at Folder` and assign a shortcut key to it.
  [image: Keyboard shortcut config]
- Option 2: If you want the shortcut key to work anywhere, create a new Service using Automator, then go to the Keyboard Shortcut to assign a shortcut key to it. Known limitation: not work from the desktop

[image]

Notes:

- If the shortcut doesn't work, it might be in conflict with another
  key binding (and the OS wouldn't warn you), try something else, e.g.
  if ⇧⌥T doesn't work, try ⇧⌘T.

Comment: Option 2 worked for me, thanks! Weird limitation of not working from the Desktop. Also I would advise against ⇧⌘T since that is a common shortcut for "reopen last closed tab"

Answer (score 7):

[iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/) - an alternative to Terminal - has an option to use configurable system-wide hotkey to show/hide (initially set to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, disabled by default)

Comment: Speaking of iTerm2.  This is what im trying to launch, using automator, but im getting that `"script"` error when i specify `tell application "iTerm2"` so how did you open `iTerm2`?

Comment: @blamb I usually open iTerm2 via this hotkey (it should be enabled in iTerm2 preferences -> keys -> Hotkey). I've never tried automator.

Comment: For more info on customising this, see this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1259726

Answer (score 1):

There is a third party app called `hotkey` app which can launch apps based on the configured shortcuts.

[image]

You can install it and setup required shortcut.

https://codenuts.de/en/posts/hotkey/

Answer (score 0):

This version of applescriopt will **reuse** the existing Terminal, while open a new one if not exists.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        if not (exists window 1) then reopen
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

Answer (score -1):

As others mentioned already, use the keyboard shortcut from services. I also had to **restart the computer to take into effect**.

Answer (score -12):

Try `command + t`.
It works for me.

Comment: This only works when the terminal app is already open or active/focused

Answer (score -12):

mac - "command + t" will open a new terminal window.

Comment: And that is  shortcut to open a new window but not a hotkey as asked in the question.