# How to define a shortcut key for opening a terminal in Mac OS

Tags: macos

I'm trying to follow the steps described on [Is there a keyboard shortcut (hotkey) to open Terminal in macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954184/is-there-any-shortcut-keyboard-method-to-open-terminal-in-mac) on Mac OS X Yosemite (version 10.10.5). However, after I save the Apple Script as "New Terminal", I don't see it among the available Services in Automator:

[image]

The Services menu contains "No Service Apply" instead of "New Terminal". How to proceed?

Comment: Is there a reason you did not do the bolded '**Set the “Service receives” popup to “no input”**' step? Your screenshot shows you didn't.

Comment: .. testing with and without that step indeed shows that's the problem. Voting to close – there is no "because you didn't follow the instructions" so I'll pick "duplicate" as well.